# Prove $u^2_n-u_{n-1}u_{n+1}=(-1)^n$ if $u_1=1,u_2=2,u_n=u_{n-1}+u_{n-2},n>2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove $u^2_n-u_{n-1}u_{n+1}=(-1)^n$ if $u_1=1,u_2=2,u_n=u_{n-1}+u_{n-2},n>2$

If $n=3$ equality is true.
How to prove this by induction?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the identity should take the form $ u_n^2 - u_{n-1}u_{n+1} = (-1)^n$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee My mistake.

Comment: Google the formula for the $n-th$ term of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Search the same problem but instead of "$u$" write "$f$" (this is the Fibonacci sequence)

Answer (score 1):

We may use the following famous trick: Notice that

$$ \begin{pmatrix}u_{n+2} \\ u_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u_{n+1} \\ u_n \end{pmatrix}. $$

Recursively using this relation, we have

$$ \begin{pmatrix}u_{n+1} & u_n \\ u_{n} & u_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{n-1} \begin{pmatrix} u_2 & u_1 \\ u_1 & u_0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Here, we extrapolate the sequence $(u_n)$ using the recurrence relation so that $u_0 = 1$. Now taking the determinant gives the desied result.